# Targeting identical data-post_id

Tags: php, jquery

So, here is the setup:

```
<?php echo '<button type="button" class="button_a" data-post_id="' .$button_id_a. '">' ;?>
     button A
<?php echo '</button>';?>
```

Then there is another button with the same `data-post_id` value:

```
<?php echo '<button type="button" class="button_b" data-post_id="' .$button_id_b. '">' ;?>
    Button B
<?php echo '</button>';?>
```

Here is script:

```
<script>
  function RebindClickModal_contact()
  {
    jQuery('.button_a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rhmp_single_form = jQuery(this).data("post_id");
         jQuery( '???????').click();
        });  
  }
  </script>
```

So, here is what I am trying achieve. When the `button A` is clicked, its `data-post_id` (as number, for example `data-post_id="123"`) is saved as a variable.

Then, I want to trigger it to click  `button B` with the same post_id value.

Now, how can I target a div with `class="button_b"` and the same `data-post_id`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
jQuery( '???????').click();
```

to this:

```
jQuery(".button_b[data-post_id='"+rhmp_single_form+"']").click();
```